# Gaussian Elimination in modulo 2 python code

Tags: python

I was wondering whether Gaussian elimination in modulo 2 (or even generally in modulo k for that purpose) has ever been implemented somewhere, so that I do not have to reinvent the wheel and just use the available resources?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a standard solution for Gauss elimination in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638650/is-there-a-standard-solution-for-gauss-elimination-in-python)

Comment: this is not a duplicate... I am asking about gaussian elimination in mod 2!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pseudo code of the algorithm you are looking for exists and is:

```
    // A is n by m binary matrix
    i := 1 // row and column index
    for i := 1 to m do // for every column
      // find non-zero element in column i, starting in row i:
      maxi := i
      for k := i to n do
        if A[k,i] = 1 then maxi := k
      end for
      if A[maxi,i] = 1 then
        swap rows i and maxi in A and b, but do not change the value of i
        Now A[i,i] will contain the old value of A[maxi,i], that is 1
        for u := i+1 to m do
          Add A[u,i] * row i to row u, do this for BOTH, matrix A and RHS vector b
          Now A[u,i] will be 0
        end for
     else
       declare error – more than one solution exist
     end if
   end for
   if n>m and if you can find zero row in A with nonzero RHS element, then
     declare error – no solution.
   end if
   // now, matrix A is in upper triangular form and solution can be found
   use back substitution to find vector x
```

Taken from this [pdf](http://dde.binghamton.edu/filler/mct/hw/1/assignment.pdf)

Binary arithmetic means arithmetic in modulo 2, which is what you are looking for in your question, if I am not wrong.

Unfortunately I don't code in Python, but if you are familiar with Python, you can simply translate the pseudo code above to Python line by line in your own way for your convenience, and this task should be **neither** difficult **nor** long.

I googled "gaussian elimination modulo 2 python", but didn't find the python code you are looking for, but I think that this is for good, because during the translation you may understand the algorithm and the method better.

EDIT 1: If you are also familiar with C# and it's not effort for you to translate C# to Python, then Michael Anderson's answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483925/how-to-implementing-gaussian-elimination-for-binary-equations) may also help you.

EDIT 2: After posting the answer, I continued the search and found [this](https://www.nayuki.io/page/gauss-jordan-elimination-over-any-field)

"over any field" implies "over modulo 2" and even "over modulo k" for any k≥2.

It contains Source Code for Java Version and **Python** version too.

According to the last link I gave you for the Python version **fieldmath.py** includes the class **BinaryField** which suppose to be the **modulo 2** as you wish.

Enjoy!

I just hope that **Gauss-Jordan elimination** and **Gaussian Elimination** are not two different things.

EDIT 3: If you are also familiar with VC++ and translating VC++ to Python is**n't** effort for you then you can also try [this](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/gaussian-elimination-in-modulo-2-vc-with-code.558239/).

I hope this well answers your question.

Comment: this is probably the best answer I ever had on here. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I am glad that you are satisfied from my answer, but sorry that I didn't notice your question earlier, because this question had to wait 1 year and 9 months, about almost 2 years, until it received a single and satisfying answer.

Comment: that is fine. It would have been very useful 2 years ago :)

Comment: At least another visitors in the future will benefit from my answer if they have same question as you had 2 years ago :) By the way that 2 years ago I started my studies in college and I learnt guassian elimination in linear algebra course and I also learnt the galois field 2, i.e. GF(2), but I learnt this in hebrew. I didn't know how it is called in english until today! That's funny for me.

Comment: haha. I had a similar story, I got into a very good university for an MSc two years ago. Did fantastically and did very well since then. Maths and programming are very worth learning. But you need only to learn enough to be "dangerous". To actually be able to do something with it.

Comment: What do you mean by "dangerous"?

Comment: So that you can make a proof of concept of your idea. Once you have that you can get someone else to finish it for you. I am taking here more about making money from your mathematical and programming knowledge :) There are tons and tons of people who are much better than you or me :)

Comment: That's I know already. I just want one day to prove that P=NP in computational complexity theory. I want to write C++ application with textbox that you can input any boolean formula in it as text string and it prints either "Yes" or "No" as output on the window, whether or not the given boolean formula is satisfiable or not. The answer will be returned after few minutes for very large and long boolean formula. Boolean Satisfiability is indeed NP-Complete and it's really difficult problem to find an efficient algorithm to solve. I am doing my best to find method to simplify the formula, but not

Comment: found yet. I am using all of my knowledge in computer science and mathematics to do this proof, but no success until now. I am planning to use my knowledge in physics too to do this proof.

Comment: Nice one! All the best of luck!

Comment: Thank you! i squared - Keep it Real! I appreciate it very much!